# React: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newCases' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, express, undefined

I want to understand why I'm getting a typeError Cannot read property 'newcases' of undefined. I have constructed a new component (Newcase.js) and based it on an existing one that works fine. But the new component always returns this error.

The index.js sends a get request:

```
 export const fetchNewCases = async () => {
  try {
    const {
      updates: { newcases},
    } = await axios.get("/api/newcases");
    return { newcases};
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

in App.js I call the function:

```
state = {
    data: {},
    wilaya: "",
    updates: {},
  };


async componentDidMount() {
    const updates = await fetchNewCases();
    this.setState({ updates });
  }
    return (
          <Fragment>
            <div className="container">
              <NewCase updates={updates} />
           </div>
          </Fragment>
        );
```

This is the Newcase.js component:

```
const NewCase = ({ newcases}) => {
  return (
    <div className="modal-main">
      <section className="modal-main">New cases: {newcases}</section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewCase;
```

On the server side, I return dummy data:

```
const updates = {
  newcases: { value: 200 },
};

app.get("/api/newcases", (req, res) => {
   res.json(updates);
});
```

Comment: In `fetchNewCases`, the variable `newcases` isn't defined anywhere. So `updates: { newcases},` is invalid. Not sure if that's where the error is from, you should highlight the specific line that's causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Basically your server/mock sends an object which has `newcases` as property and you are trying to destructure the property `updates` which is incorrect. Also, axios provides the result inside `data`. So first destructure `data` then do nested destructure of `newcases`

**Do this**

```js
export const fetchNewCases = async () => {
  try {
    const {data: {newcases} } = await axios.get("/api/newcases");
    return { newcases};
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

2. In app.js you are passing `updates` in app.js `<NewCase updates={updates} />` and in `Newcase.js` you are receiving prop as `newcases` which is incorrect

**Do this**

```js
 const NewCase = ({ updates}) => { ...
```

**Update**(based on comment)

3. in app.js you should pass `this.state.updates` (not just updates)

**App.js**

```js
state = {
    data: {},
    wilaya: "",
    updates: {},
  };


async componentDidMount() {
    const updates = await fetchNewCases();
    this.setState({ updates });
  }
    return (
          <Fragment>
            <div className="container">
              <NewCase updates={this.state.updates} /> //<------ like this
           </div>
          </Fragment>
        );
```

Comment: I updated the api call as per @gdh's answer. I'm not getting the typeError anymore, but I'm getting a returned object with: {newcases: undefined}

Comment: i see - can you pls put ur code in sandbox and provide a link..

Comment: it's working now: yes the problem was in the destructuring. This is what I changed:  const { data } = await axios.get("/api/newcases");
    const modifiedData = {
      newcases: data.newcases.value,
    };